# Clojure : force evaluation of code with return value

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have had an issue with my code due to a very twisted behaviour of a function.

I use google-api to stream data in BigQuery. In Java, you create an object called `Bigquery.Tabledata.InsertAll` (a request) and then you execute it

```
TableDataInsertAllResponse response = request.execute();
```

(sample code from Google)

But as you can see, the execution is something that has side effect while returning a response.

I reproduced it in Clojure (in a chunked fashion)

```
(defn load-bq
  [client project-id dataset-id table-id data & {:keys [chunk-size] :or {chunk-size 500}}]
  (let [chunks (partition-all chunk-size data)
        _ (str "Now streaming data into table : [" project-id ":" dataset-id "." table-id "]")]
    (map (partial atomic-load-bq client project-id dataset-id table-id) chunks)))
```

If I try to stream in repl, it works fine. But surpinsingly a doall does not work in code like in a let or with a do.
Here a function to illustrate the principle

```
(def load-this-table
  [... data]
  (let [_ (doall (load-bq ... data))]
    (load-bq ... data)
    (do (load-bq ...data))))
```

Here, nothing will be loaded.

I found a trick that works though it is a bit far-fetched :

```
(def load-this-table
  [... data]
  (let [_ (println (load-bq ... data))]
    (println (load-bq ... data))))
```

Here both line will execute. of course i need only one streaming so I chose a single solution here.

How to force evaluation of this code without having to use println ?
I could use what force evaluation behing println or any more general core function.

I have the impression that the difference is not really linked to lazyness but more to a more fundamental difference bewteen Clojure and Java. And maybe that the response have to be "taken" by the client.

Thanks !

Comment: It looks like `atomic-load-bq` is lazy, so you are forcing evaluation of the chunks with `doall`, however the contents of the chunks are lazy. Printing a sequence of sequences will realize all the values (deep expansion), but doall will only realize the top level sequence. Please note that `doseq` is probably better, and that `doseq` can take multiple bindings so you can conveniently represent the nesting.

Comment: @TimothyPratley seems like an answer.

Comment: You are probably right. There is no real lazy material inside but definitely something to evaluate so I will add a do[x] function inside atomic load. For now println is not that bad since I have also a king of debugger